# Display same model twice in KeystoneJS admin based on a property

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I'm working on a quiz backend and administration tool and thought that KeystoneJS would be great for this purpose. An idea i have is to have a question category class which can have a relationship to itself as child/parent. This way i could reuse the same class for both top level categories and subcategories.

While I seem to be able to configure the basic relationship itself, how would I go about presenting categories without subcategories on one page, and the subcategories on another? To be even more specific, i want one admin page that says "categories" and another to say "subcategories".

Or, is there a better approach to this? Could i perhaps use some kind of tree view that I'm unaware of? Or something completely different? I'm open to suggestions as long as I get a clean easily maintainable category system that supports subcategories.

Here is a simplified version of my QuestionCategory:

http://pastie.org/private/atmlggv3wixz78mioyn6q

Comment: i have the same requirements and issue did you get any solution .Can you please help me if you get any ?

Comment: Unfortunately i never solved this. It was abandoned due to time constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your response dear ..